# ruby variable inside sql statement

Tags: sql, ruby, string

I am trying to use a ruby variable inside an sql statement. The following code works and deletes the second record of the templates table. How do i replace this number with my user defined variable "deleteid"?

```
deleteid = gets.chomp
$db.execute %q{DELETE FROM templates
WHERE id = 2}
```

Comment: Which database driver is in `$db`? Just throwing unescaped values into SQL is criminally irresponsible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string interpolation:

```
$db.execute %{DELETE FROM templates WHERE id = #{deleteid}}

$db.execute %Q{DELETE FROM templates WHERE id = #{deleteid}}
```

**UPDATE**

User can pass arbitrary string. Using `deleteid` directly can be dangerous. As @muistooshort commented, you should escape the `deleteid`.

Consult your db driver's documentation for methods that accepts parameter and escape the parameter (or `prepare` method).

For example, if you use sqlite3-ruby, you can use [`Database#query`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/master/SQLite3/Database:query), which will escape for you.

```
$db.prepare(%q{DELETE FROM templates WHERE id = ?}, [deleteid])
```

in pg, use [`Connection#exec_params`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection:exec_params):

```
$db.exec_params(%q{DELETE FROM templates WHERE id = $1}, [deleteid])
```